# How to find the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[ a \mathcal{Q} \left( \sqrt{b } \gamma \right) \right]$?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to find the following expectation

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ a \mathcal{Q} \left( \sqrt{b } \gamma \right) \right],$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constant values, $\mathcal{Q}$ is the Gaussian Q-function, which is defined as $\mathcal{Q}(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2}du$ and $\gamma$ is a random variable with Gamma distribition, i.e., $f_{\gamma}(y) \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(\kappa)\theta^{\kappa}} y^{\kappa-1} e^{-y/\theta} $.

I have tried to solve that with Mathematica, however, it says it does not converge.

Comment: Define: `q[x_] := 1/(2 π) Integrate[Exp[-u^2/2], {u, x, ∞}]` `G = GammaDistribution[α, β, γ, μ];`  `gpdf = PDF[G, g];`. Then `Expectation[a q[Sqrt[b] g], g \[Distributed] G]` , but this will not work, neither will `Integrate[a q[Sqrt[b] g]*gpdf, {g, 0,∞}]`. It's too complicated for Mathematica - however if you have values for the gamma distribution parameters, then this is quite easy even with unknown constants a,b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too hard to set this up. I had no luck with the more complex four parameter `GammaDistribution` but fortunately you only mentioned the two parameter version:

```
q[x_] = 1/(2 π) Integrate[Exp[-u^2/2], {u, x, ∞}]
G = GammaDistribution[κ, θ];
gpdf = PDF[G, y]
result = a*Expectation[q[Sqrt[b] y], y \[Distributed] G]
```

Result:

```
2^(-3 - κ/2) a b^(-(1/2) - κ/
  2) θ^(-1 - κ) (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
    b] θ HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(1 + κ)/
      2, κ/2}, {1/2, (2 + κ)/2}, 1/(
     2 b θ^2)] - κ HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(
      1 + κ)/2, (2 + κ)/2}, {3/2, (3 + κ)/2}, 1/(
     2 b θ^2)])
```

Let's do a quick check to make sure it returned something reasonable. We'll generate some gamma distributed random numbers, apply the function and get the mean. Then also use these constants with our result obtained earlier to confirm it's a close match to this numerical experiment:

```
qn[x_?NumericQ] := 1/(2 π) NIntegrate[Exp[-u^2/2], {u, x, ∞}]
With[{κ = 1, θ = 2, a = 4, b = 3},
 rands = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[κ, θ], 5000];
 Mean[a*qn[Sqrt[b]*#] & /@ rands]
]
(* result: 0.155478 *)

N[result /. {κ -> 1, θ -> 2, a -> 4, b -> 3}]
(* result: 0.15502 *)
```

Looks about right!

---

Your version of the [Q-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) has `1/(2 π)`. I think this should be `1/Sqrt[2 π]` instead. In which case the result changes:

```
q[x_] = 1/Sqrt[2 π] Integrate[Exp[-u^2/2], {u, x, ∞}]
G = GammaDistribution[κ, θ];
gpdf = PDF[G, y]
result = a*Expectation[q[Sqrt[b] y], y \[Distributed] G]
```

Result:

```
2^(-(5/2) - κ/2) a b^(-(1/2) - κ/
  2) Sqrt[π] θ^(-1 - κ) (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
    b] θ HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(1 + κ)/
      2, κ/2}, {1/2, (2 + κ)/2}, 1/(
     2 b θ^2)] - κ HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(
      1 + κ)/2, (2 + κ)/2}, {3/2, (3 + κ)/2}, 1/(
     2 b θ^2)])
```

Comment: +1.  Also, `dist = TransformedDistribution[a q[Sqrt[b] y], y \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[\[Kappa], \[Theta]]]; Mean[dist]]` works, too.

Comment: +1 Recommend that the definition of `q` use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` so that the integral is only done once. Also, in the check with random variates you can use `q` rather than `qn`.

Comment: For whatever it's worth: $q(x)=\frac{\text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$.